# Why do data classes not implement Serializable?

Tags: kotlin, serialization

I am new to `kotlin` but a veteran of `scala`. The former has impressed me so far. But at this moment I am working through a head scratcher - that the `data class` does not implement `Serializable`. How a class with that name could expected to *not* be routinely expected to be used in that manner eludes me.

What are the technical challenge(s) that precluded that support?  I'm interested because i'd like to create a wrapper. It seems that the expectation is to always provide a `serializer()` ?  That is cumbersome and actually `kotlinx.serialization` is not working for me yet - even after some effort.

Comment: I don't know if this is the reason, but Brian Goetz has said on multiple occasions that serialization was one of Java's worst mistakes. I think Kotlin is right not to encourage its use.

Comment: Would that require all the class's properties to be Serializable too?

Comment: @gidds  The way it works in `scala` `case class` is that all of the fields in the contructor are included by the compiler for serialization. If you add more fields internally then it's up to you . I'm not trying to do anything fancy here: just the constructor fields are fine.

Comment: does this works for you? https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/examples.md the annotation for becoming serializable

Comment: @AnimeshSahu  No it is not working.

Comment: @javadba you could chat with devs in serialization channel in the official kotlinlang slack or could raise an issue in the github repository since i didn't found resources on data class serialization.

Comment: @Jorn, I don't think Goetz is opposed to serialization, just the way it's implemented in Java. "Magic code" that is hidden to the programmer and makes serialization error-prone, hard to reason about, hard to maintain, and encapsulation-breaking.

Comment: @Tenfour04 Exactly! And the Serializable interface encourages its use, which is why it shouldn't be used. Feel free to serialize in other ways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a bit unclear from the question if you mean `java.io.Serializable` (based on the analogy with Scala and "implement") or `kotlinx.serialization.Serializable` (based on the second paragraph and discussion in the comments).

First, for the Java one:

I think the way you should phrase it is: why do data classes not implement `Serializable` *by default*? You can always add `: Serializable` if you want.

Then you can note this isn't the only place where Kotlin requires you to be more explicit than Scala. For another data class example, you need to mark properties by `val` or `var` where Scala assumes `val` by default. And for non-data classes, Scala allows you to use non-`val` constructor parameters inside the class effectively promoting them to `private val` where Kotlin doesn't.

For `Serializable` in particular:

1. It would privilege Java serialization which has bad reputation (as mentioned in the comments already).
2. `Serializable` isn't usable in cross-platform (or just Kotlin/JS or Kotlin/Native) projects. Maybe data classes could only be serializable on JVM, but it would be an unnecessary mismatch between platforms.
3. case classes implement `Serializable` even if they have non-`Serializable` properties and will throw if you actually try to serialize them.
4. In the common case of multiple case classes extending a trait, if you forget to make the trait `extends Product with Serializable` type inference [often gives ugly types](https://typelevel.org/blog/2018/05/09/product-with-serializable.html).

For Kotlin Serialization, the answer is even simpler: you don't want a basic language feature like data classes to depend on an experimental and immature library. I wouldn't be surprised if data classes do become `@Serializable` by default when it "graduates" like coroutines did in 1.3.

Comment: I want to be able to use `kotlin` libraries that _already_ use `kotlinx.serializable` or `kotlin.serializable` :   `Kaml` is the particular one.  Since `data class` is not serializable it becomes necessary to use an annotation and a custom serializer.  It turns out `Intellij` can't understand that (even untouched directly from https://github.com/charleskorn/kaml and so I'm stuck with a non-working  project.

Comment: "IntelliJ can't understand that" is a very different problem from "data class is not serializable" (again, by default). If anything, it's additional evidence kotlinx serialization is immature and shouldn't be enabled by default!

Comment: `kotlin.serialization` doesn't exist and so can't be used by any library. It will be added when... you guessed it, the `kotlinx` version becomes finished. Just like with coroutines.

Comment: For a Scala analogy, think of Kotlin Serialization like Argonaut or Circe libraries and of `@Serializable` as having to write `implicit def PersonCodecJson = ...`. Yes, Kotlin Serialization is implemented by the Kotlin team but it isn't part of the language (yet).

Comment: I did notice there is  some kind of implicits happening. I guess maybe just dump the `kaml` library

Comment: I've had significant issues with kolin/IJ which surprised me.