# Is Kotlin data class serializable by default?

Tags: kotlin, serialization, data-class

After knowing Kotlin, love the `data class`.
I could replace Java classes that has `equal` and `hash` and `toString` to it.
Most of these Java classes are `serializable` class. So my question is, when we convert to `data class`, do I still need to make it `serializable` explicitly? like

```
data class SomeJavaToKotlinClass(val member: String) : Serializable
```

Or it is okay to be

```
data class SomeJavaToKotlinClass(val member: String)
```

Comment: In https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61094618/why-do-data-classes-not-implement-serializable/61109799#61109799 I described some reasons why they aren't and shouldn't be (in my opinion, I don't know any official answers).

Comment: Nice one. Thanks @AlexeyRomanov. That's a very nice explanation. I think my question is valid as the fact that data class implement all the function that is required by serialization will cause user like me to assume that's what it has by default. But glad to know the exact answer.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No, Kotlin data classes do not implicitly implement this interface. You can see from [this example](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS4zLjYxIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiaW1wb3J0IGphdmEuaW8uU2VyaWFsaXphYmxlXG5cbmRhdGEgY2xhc3MgRm9vKHZhbCBiYXI6IFN0cmluZylcblxuZnVuIGFjY2VwdHNTZXJpYWxpemFibGUoczogU2VyaWFsaXphYmxlKSB7IH1cblxuZnVuIG1haW4oYXJnczogQXJyYXk8U3RyaW5nPikge1xuICAgIHZhbCBmOiBGb28gPSBGb28oXCJiYXpcIilcbiAgICBhY2NlcHRzU2VyaWFsaXphYmxlKGYpXG59In0=):

```kotlin
import java.io.Serializable

data class Foo(val bar: String)

fun acceptsSerializable(s: Serializable) { }

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val f: Foo = Foo("baz")
    
    // The following line produces the compiler error:
    // Type mismatch: inferred type is Foo but Serializable was expected
    acceptsSerializable(f)
}
```

Comment: Or just `println(Foo("") is Serializable)`.

Comment: For anyone looking at how to serialize a data class if it doesn't work by default, have a look at the `kotlinx-serialization` plugin. With this, you can just put `@Serializable` to your data class and its serializable. This article sums it up really well: https://betterprogramming.pub/why-and-how-to-use-kotlins-native-serialization-library-c88c0f14f93d

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov True, but it will also not compile with the error `Incompatible types: Serializable and Foo`. The example in the answer returns the error `Type mismatch: inferred type is Foo but Serializable was expected`.

Answer (score 20):

I had to add `: Serializable` at the end of class to make is Serializable. Just like this

```
class SizeVariantModel (val price: Double, val discountedPrice: Double?) : Serializable
class ColorVariantModel (val name: String, val colorCode: String) : Serializable
```

I also had to import `Serializable`

```
import java.io.Serializable
```

Comment: Thanks for the import. Android Studio wasn't suggesting it :·)